# event.target.value - взять одно значение из двух

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Возникла необходимость добавить выпадающий список с двумя значениями - условно контактом и его ID, одной строкой. Выбранное значение обрабатывается через event.target.value. Однако это значение берёт всю выбранную пользователем строку, а мне нужен только ID. Есть ли возможность его как-то отделить?

Впервые столкнулся с JS, так что извиняюсь заранее, если вопрос некорректный или элементарный.

HTML:

```
<select class="slds-select" name = "contactSelect" onchange={changeHandler}>
    <template for:each={allContacts.data} for:item="contact">
       <!-- мне нужен только {contact.Id}, пользователю - оба поля -->
       <option key={contact.Id} value={contactId}>{contact.Name}, {contact.Id}</option>    
    </template>
</select>
```

Обработчик:

```
changeHandler(event) {
  const field = event.target.name;

    // здесь я получаю оба значения одной строкой, нужно одно
    if (field === 'contactSelect') {
        this.contactId = event.target.value;
        }
    // здесь я получаю оба значения одной строкой, нужно одно
    if (field === 'accountSelect') {
        this.accountId = event.target.value;
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var key = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('key');
if (field === 'contactSelect') {
    this.contactId = key;
}
if (field === 'accountSelect') {
    this.accountId = key;
}
```